# How can I add an item with unicode characters to a QComboBox in python?

Tags: python-2.7, qt, unicode, pyqt, qcombobox

I am trying to add prefixed units to a `QComboBox` in python, depending on the range of the parameter. The problem is that when I try to add a "μ" it comes out as "Î1/4" which is not what I want.

The code I am currently using is:

```
def build_unit_box(self, measure):
    listed = []
    if measure in {'P', 'frep'}:
        for pref in ['', 'k', 'M', 'G']:
            listed.append(str(pref + units.get(measure)))
        exec("%s" % 'self.unit_' + measure + '.addItems(listed)')
    elif measure in {'W', 'lambda', 'tau'}:
        for pref in ['', 'm', u'\u03bc'.encode('utf-8'), 'n']:
            print pref
            listed.append(str(pref + units.get(measure)))
        exec("%s" % 'self.unit_' + measure + '.addItems(listed)')
```

If I type `print u'\u03bc'` the correct character is printed.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. As i had copy-pasted some of the code from another function, I was typecasting the characters to `str` which resulted in the wrong encoding.
It works perfectly with:

```
def build_unit_box(self, measure):
    listed = []
    if measure in {'P', 'frep'}:
        for pref in ['', 'k', 'M', 'G']:
            listed.append(str(pref + units.get(measure)))
        exec("%s" % 'self.unit_' + measure + '.addItems(listed)')
    elif measure in {'W', 'lambda', 'tau'}:
        for pref in ['', 'm', u'\u03bc', 'n']:
            print pref
            listed.append(unicode(pref + units.get(measure)))
        exec("%s" % 'self.unit_' + measure + '.addItems(listed)')
```